# How to "correctly" add an existing entity to a collection RESTfully

Tags: rest

I have two already extant objects,

```
/foo/1 GET
/bar/1 GET
```

Each `foo` has `bar`s and each `bar` has `foo`s.  How do I RESTfully add my `bar` to my `foo`'s `bar` collection?

This seems like one possible interpretation:

```
/foo/1 PATCH { bars: [1] }
```

but it breaks the idea that `bar`s attached to that `foo` should be displayed via `/foo/1/bar/`.  This also seems valid:

```
/foo/1/bar/ POST { id: 1, ... }
```

and fits closest to the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) description, but since we're not creating a new `bar` this is a bit confusing.  This also creates a kind of bizarre ambiguity, since it may also be possible to create a new `bar` assigned to this `foo` via this method.  Lastly, there's:

```
/foo/1/bar/1 POST
```

which I just plain *like* due to its simplicity, but doesn't agree with the wikipedia description and gives no obvious way to remove the `bar` from the list (since `DELETE` would delete the `bar`).

I realize REST is an architectural style rather than an explicit standard, but there must be some least-problematic way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually see this solved by using a third resource to own the mapping between foo and bar, such as:

```
POST /foo
<- "id": 22

POST /bar
<- "id": 17

POST /foo-bars
-> { "fooId": 22, "barId": 17 }
```

Comment: While this provides one solution, it's a bit ugly and creates a whole bunch of relating objects that are nothing but foreign keys.  If possible, I'd like to avoid exposing those intermediary objects directly to the frontend to avoid a lot of excess calls.